# JS Object formatting in html issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that renders an object in html.

```
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background: #ddd;
}

.item h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

I seem to be missing a formatting issue. The JS compiles properly, no errors, but both the h4 tag and the h5 tag render outside the , even though in code the closing div tag is after the h4 and h5 tags. 
Here ids the HTML after it gets rendered in the browser

```
<div class="menuHolder" id="menuContainer">
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < foodItems.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("menuContainer").innerHTML += '<div class="item"> <img src="' +  foodItems[i].image + '" >';
  document.getElementById("menuContainer").innerHTML += '<h4> ' +  foodItems[i].name + '</h4>';
  document.getElementById("menuContainer").innerHTML += '<h5> $' +  foodItems[i].price + '</h5>';
  document.getElementById("menuContainer").innerHTML += '</div>';
  console.log("Item: " + foodItems[i].name + " Cost: $" + foodItems[i].price);
}
```

```css
.item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background: #ddd;
}

.item h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item h5 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuHolder" id="menuContainer">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/hamburger.jpg"></div>
  <h4>Hamburger</h4>
  <h5>$2.99</h5><div class="item">
  <img src="images/fries.jpg"></div>
  <h4>Fries</h4>
  <h5>$1.99</h5>
  <div class="item"> 
    <img src="images/donuts.jpg">
  </div>
  <h4>Donuts</h4>
  <h5>$0.99</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to build the string, and then set the innerHTML - when setting inner HTML, the divs are parsed into nodes and most modern browsers will close any open div tags

Comment: you mean concatenate the whole block into one string?

Comment: Or just replace: `document.getElementById("menuContainer").innerHTML =` with `myStr =` and then do `document.getElementById("menuContainer").innerHTML = myStr;` after the last myStr addage

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I thought about that briefly as a solution, but didn't think it was that simple. Makes sense once I think about it though.

Comment: Sorry for my Aweful formatting of question. This is the first time i have asked a question on Stack overflow in 4 or 5 years

Comment: All good, javascript is odd in how it does thing - especially when it comes to specific browser related bugs.

Comment: @Derek What bugs are you referring to?

Comment: @torazaburo **IE**

Comment: @MrLister My mistake, I have just added the script back, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foodItems.length; i++) {
    var tmpstr = '<div class="item"> <img src="' +  foodItems[i].image + '" >';
    tmpstr += '<h4> ' +  foodItems[i].name + '</h4>';
    tmpstr += '<h5> $' +  foodItems[i].price + '</h5>';
    tmpstr += '</div>';
    document.getElementById("menuContainer").innerHTML = tmpstr;
    console.log("Item: " + foodItems[i].name + " Cost: $" + foodItems[i].price);
}
```

When you added string to innerHTML, browsers may "auto correct" the html and added  at the end.

P.S. you may need to take care of escaping characters in your foodItems[i].name.

Comment: If you're going to be building HTML strings like this, you would be much better off using ES6 template strings.